# Scope and MySQLi binding

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been using the old MySQL library for PHP for ages now and I've finally caved into using MySQLi. Prepared statements seem very useful, so I'm trying to get the hang out them.

Right now I'm creating some prepared statements and binding their parameters globally, and then using a function to execute them like this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT ...");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $var1, $var2);

function process($t) {
    global $mysqli, $stmt;
    $var1 = $t['var1'];
    $var2 = $t['var2'];
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that the execute function runs into an error where the variables are still null. Should I be binding/unbinding as I gather values from `$t`?

Comment: `bind_param()` takes variable references, so if you call it outisde the function, need to access `$var1,$var2` globally inside the function as well.  The ones inside the function are of local scope, not the same variables you bound outside.

Comment: Of course! I thought MySQLi was doing some magic with `bind_param`--it's still fairly early here, so excuse the cognitive flatulence.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm such a dummy:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES(?, ?)");

function process($t) { 
    global $mysqli, $stmt;
    $var1 = $t['var1'];
    $var2 = $t['var2'];
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $var1, $var2);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

I thought that MySQLi was doing some magic binding with variables. 
In this case `bind_param` just places the values in the prepared statement, rather than declaring in stone that certain variables are 'bound' to the statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think placing the code like this should work:
(Assuming the variables in the $t array() exist)

```
function process ($t) {
  global $mysqli; 
  $var1 = $t['var1'];     
  $var2 = $t['var2'];

  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT ..."); 
  $stmt->bind_param("ss", $var1, $var2);  
  $stmt->execute();

}
```

Comment: I have reasons for making my prepared statement global (since I don't want to prepare a new statement every time I recur through process). I don't think this gets at my point of confusion though, which was what `bind_param` actually does..